# How can CVE-2020-25638 be reproduced?

Tags: hibernate

There was a recent SQL injection bug in hibernate

http://jvn.jp/en/jp/JVN90729322/index.html

I find it intriguing that the error is related to comments. Is that supposed to happen when a query has a parameter inside a comment? What does that even mean?

I haven't found any example on how to reproduce it, or write up. Could someone explain what is the CVE about?

Comment: https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html . My guess is that comments might not get sanitized from the input if this is enabled .

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss the link you pasted is just the generic definition of sql injection. I understand what that is. My question is how are parameters related to comments? Is the driver escaping the value in the parameter and failing to do so properly when it has a comment string? Or is it a parameter inside a comment?

First one, is a surprise to me, I would expect the driver to use proper parameters to avoid sql injection, not just escaping values. Second one, I don't really get the point.

Comment: Isnt it explained how comment syntax can can be used to inject commands there?

Comment: It's explained how comments can lead to sql injection in query substitution. That's a whole different thing. If there is query substitution you can do all kind of nasty things.

But this CVE is with parametric queries, which should protect against injection

Comment: This is why i guess that when comments are on, comments inside parameters might not be sanitized - again, bling guess

Comment: At least in postgres parameter queries are a whole different beast to normal queries. It's not like parameters are escaped and a single query passed to the db driver.

The db driver will receive the query along with the parameters, so there is no room for injection, one is code the other is data